# Quick 3D sight calculation algorithm

Tags: 3d, tiles, path-finding, raycasting, line-of-sight

I have a tile based board game where units move in 3D space on a 2D isometric view. When calculating attack tiles for a unit, how do I verify that they aren't shooting through a wall or a level too high for them see. I need quickly verify a lot of these attack tiles are within a unit's range of sight (about 20). What's the fastest way I can verify line of sight with the x, y, and z axis?

Somebody posted a similar question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/quick-2d-sight-area-calculation-algorithm), but it covers 2D sight calculation instead of 3D (making the answer very different).

Answer (score 3):

Use [3D DDA](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2010/course/TDA361/grid.pdf). It is the 3D version of 2D cell-based raycasting which you refer to.

Comment: Pseudo code seems fairly easy to understand. To see the 3D code sample look under "The New Traversal Algorithm" section in the second code snippet.

Comment: Okay, I think the PDF you linked to works. The problem is I can't figure out what tMaxX/tMaxY/tMaxZ and tDeltaX/tDeltaY/tDeltaZ are equal to. Document is a bit vague on how to get these values.